# Hide menubar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a content using H5P plugin.I want admin to see only create content option in wordpress and want to hide rest of the menu bar option. Can anybody please tell how can I achieve this?

Comment: Share your code and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes share your code. else you can use is_admin() function to check if admin or not

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand the use case. Do you want the H5P Editor to appear on a page without any other components, appear outside of /wp-admin or do you simply wish to hide some of the menu options for certain roles?